# curl POST into C#

Tags: c#, curl

I am trying to find a way how to transfer curl command to C#.

What i need is to obtain token from api and save it into file C:\...\x.json\

Then i want to declare token into variable, and use it into another curl POST request to take data to work with them.

Curl:

```
curl -X POST "https://example.com" 
-H "accept: application/json" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d {"username":"username","password":"password"}
```

My current try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://example.com"))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");

            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"username\":\"username\",\"password\":\"password\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }                        
}
```

I tried several things, but none of them was working. This one is from curl.olsh.me but also i am getting some await error what i don't know what to do with it. (I am newbie in C#) :

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

curl -v output:

- - Trying 10.0.0.0...
  - TCP_NODELAY set
  - Connected to example.com (10.0.0.0) port 443 (#0)
  - ALPN, offering h2
  - ALPN, offering http/1.1
  - successfully set certificate verify locations:
  - CAfile: C:\Users\lvrabel\Downloads\curl-7.60.0-win64-mingw\curl-7.60.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
    CApath: none
  - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
  - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
  - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  - SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
  - ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
  - Server certificate:
  - subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard; CN=*.example.com
  - start date: Dec  1 00:00:00 2016 GMT
  - expire date: Dec  1 23:59:59 2019 GMT
  - subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "*.example.com"
  - issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server
  - SSL certificate verify ok.
    < POST /cxf/IOTServices/v2/Login HTTP/1.1
    < Host: example.com
    < User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
    < accept: application/json
    < Content-Type: application/json
    < Content-Length: 64
    <
  - upload completely sent off: 64 out of 64 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 09:22:30 GMT
    < Content-Type: application/json
    < Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 09:22:31 GMT
    < Connection: close
    < Set-Cookie: TS0119a36f=015d568915873c94e852616fd92d5dd7a03a620f3cd2326781154684dfd7b31302f6fcb9822598d5a76466d0c6a25583fccbb30c7d; Path=/; Domain=.example.com
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    <
    {"code":200,"status":"success","sessionId":"5cd92d80-bfdb-11e8-83c7-5b742f0c1244"}* Closing connection 0
  - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):

Comment: Your method sig should look like:   `static async void Main(string[] args)`. You add the `async` keyword.

Comment: Hi @Stuart, then i don't understand it, because when i change Main method then i got error : Program does not contain static Main method suitable for an entry point

Comment: You might want to define a task method, and then call that from within Main...

Comment: @LukášVrábel check my answer, that might solve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

use this website 
https://curl.olsh.me/

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://example.com/"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json"); 

        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"username\":\"username\",\"password\":\"password\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you need to convert username and password to bytes, and take it as base 64 string and pass it to header. When you use await, if it is a void method then you should add async modifier with Task in its signature OR in case the method should return what ever type than use async Task as shown in the example. In that case you need to fetch the result, using result as shown in the test example. You can read more on this topic in [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) docs.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateAuthorization(string url, string username, string password)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), url))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
            var authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {authorization}");
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

Here is example of testing it:

```
public void CreateAuthorizationTest()
{
    var response = CreateAuthorization("https://example.com", "username", "password");
    var result = response.Result;
    var o = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //do some thing if success
        // you can do deserialization what ever
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
    else
    {
        //do some thing if error
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
    //etc.
}
```

Links:

- [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await/19985988)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Can you show the request code? It's the passing of the post data that's problematic. I've been using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as well.

Comment: @user1274820 just to be sure the other answer got the bounty so I assume you got the answer. so I also assume that my answer is irrelevant. If you think I can contribute more let me know so I can look at it when I have time, it is late night at my location.

Comment: Wtf I gave the bounty to you... you were supposed to get it dude

Comment: I started another bounty - I can award it to you in 23 hours  sorry about that man

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778801/logging-into-salesforce-with-c-sharp-httpclient

Comment: I think you can change it or before putting bounty on me try to write to moderator see if this can be corrected. Regardless I will look at it tomrrow.

Comment: @user1274820 I am back just so I can follow up correctly, did you solved issue or can I still help?

Comment: I got it figured out - finally let me award you the bounty - thanks man! 

Comment: No problems I am happy you solved it. The best luck forward

Answer (score 2):

Async main methods is available in C# 7. If you're on an earlier version, you can handle the task 'manually' like this

```
var task = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
task.Wait();
var response = task.Result;
Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Comment: Nice that is working, thank you for that. I do have respond from server right now, but sadly i see just this : StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

Where should be also token, but i dont see it.

Comment: Actually more specifically, since 7.1

Comment: @LukášVrábel Since you're getting a 200 return code, the call is going through to the server. You could try to debug on the server side if you have access to it to see what is going on. If you don't have access to the server, you could try getting the call to work with Postman or something like that.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to that server. Syntax of the token is something like this: _6fa3ea90-bc02-11e8-991a-d35512019464_. That should be problem for Encoding right?

Comment: Can you post the output from curl in your question?

Comment: @HansKilian Sorry i was out of PC at the weekend. Here is the output i need: _{"code":200,"status":"success","sessionId":"1306d850-ba68-11e8-991a-d35512019464"}_

Comment: My mistake. I wanted to see the headers, so could you run curl with the -v option and add the output to the question?

Comment: pastebin is blocked in our firewall :(

Comment: @HansKilian I added it to my original question.

Comment: The only weird thing I can see is that you have 'accept' in your curl command but 'Accept' in the program. But 'Accept' should be the correct one.

Comment: I think that this one doesn't really matter. Whole ouput in console looks like this: StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Content-Length: 738
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}

Comment: The content you get back is an HTML page. That's usually an error page when that happens. Can you check if there's any useful information in it?

Comment: I have no idea how to check it in html sorry. Can you tell me how please?

Comment: If i add it into the code i get request declined. But when I leave it as it was so just Console.WriteLine(response); then the statuscode is 200 so i have no idea...

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the main method `async`:

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
```

If you are using C# version < 7.1, then you cannot use any await directly in `Main`. In this case you have to define a `Task` and `.Wait()` for it (instead of `await` for it).

```
Task task = ....;
task.Wait();
var result = task.Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension

example:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
// Add NuGet package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension
namespace SimpleRestCall
{
    class Program
    {
        static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        static readonly string sitePath = "https://example.com";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(sitePath), Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0) })
            {
                Task.Run(() => Login(client)).Wait();
            }
        }

        private static async Task Login(HttpClient client)
        {
            string path = ""; // if it's a controller path put it here
            LoginData postData = new LoginData { username = "username", password = "password" };
            string json;
            using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, postData, cts.Token))
            {
                json = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to finish");
            string aa = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private class LoginData
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I got this response from server :

> StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 06:57:16 GMT
>     Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 06:57:17 GMT
>     Connection: close
>     Set-Cookie: TS0119a36f=015d56898097bc7f5dccb374f352898f8806da5833c9f8a8ef4ff6ae2a2b1d4e78147fb79479f8bf85929406f34372c41c63572a89; Path=/; Domain=.example.com
>     Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>     Content-Type: application/json
>   }

I think that there is some problem with encoding or idk. When i execute curl i get this output (the one i need):

> {"code":200,"status":"success","sessionId":"350bf800-bfdb-11e8-991a-d35510009464"}

Current code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.example.com"))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
                request.Content = new StringContent("{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"pass\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var task = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                task.Wait();
                var response = task.Result;

                Console.WriteLine(response);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```