# Logging into Salesforce with C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, salesforce, dotnet-httpclient

I can't seem to get this code to work:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://login.salesforce.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "SFAPIClient"); //Random Client
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters["grant_type"] = "password";
parameters["client_id"] = CLIENT_ID;
parameters["client_secret"] = CLIENT_SECRET;
parameters["username"] = t_username.Text;
parameters["password"] = t_password.Text;
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oath2/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Salesforce keeps responding with "this url no longer exists" which is what CURL was responding with before I got it working.

The CURL code I'm trying to mimic is:

`curl [salesforce url] -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=[clientId]" -d "client_secret=[clientSecret]" -d "username=[username]" -d "password=[password]"`

^ after running this the server responds with:

`{"access_token":"[token]","instance_url":[etc...]}"`

I'm hoping to get the same response in C# - it's been pretty annoying so far.

Comment: you said it was not working for curl and then it started working.. what did you change?

Comment: the endpoint for oauth seems to be incorrect. are you sure what you are using is fine...  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_oauth_endpoints.htm

Comment: @indolentdeveloper I was originally using the -X curl parameter before I think. I'm pretty sure that was what I changed.

Comment: @indolentdeveloper from your link: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` - that's what I'm using and it's working just fine for curl. I tried it with an extra `/` and without.

Comment: can you try running this in postman or this [https://curl.olsh.me] to convert your code to c# and see if that works.

Comment: @indolentdeveloper the `curl.olsh.me` code gives me an SSL error when I try to run it. That seems to be remedied by adding `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` to the code.

Comment: Please see my edit for the curl output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`client.PostAsync("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oath2/token")` has a typo - it should be `oauth2`, you're missing a letter.

Comment: No way... if this is seriously the problem I'm going to facepalm so hard.

Comment: Dude OMFG I swear I looked at that URL 100 times... I cannot believe this. Thanks so much man